# Adding an if statement in a for loop leads to "unexpected '}' in "}"" error

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
for (i in -4:4){
  if (i =! 0){
    segments(i,0,i,dnorm(i))
  }
}
```

When I execute it, it throws this error:

> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Before adding the if statement the lines were added by the segment function to the plot without any problems. What's the problem with the if statement?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In R not equal is `!=`

Comment: I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo: it should be `if (i != 0)`:

```
plot(-40:40/10, dnorm(-40:40/10), type = "l")

for (i in -4:4){
  if (i != 0){
    segments(i,0,i,dnorm(i))
  }
}
```